# Create a JAXRSClientBean using a service class with multipart-formdata

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, cxf

I've successfully created a small server using Jersey 2.1, including jersey-media-multipart to be able to upload files.

Now I want to develop a simple client using Apache CXF, using the same interface as my server does.

### Code

Simplified, my code looks like the following:

```
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

/**
 * @author outofrange
 */
public class JaxRSClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JAXRSClientFactoryBean bean = new JAXRSClientFactoryBean();
        bean.setServiceClass(MultipartRestService.class);
        bean.setAddress("http://www.google.at");
        bean.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());     

        bean.create(MultipartRestService.class).multipathRequest(Files.newInputStream(new File("pom.xml").toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ));
    }
}

@Path("/multipart")
interface MultipartRestService {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    Response multipathRequest(@FormDataParam("inputStream") InputStream inputStream);

}
```

### Log

I can see that CXF uses multipart/formdata as the Content-Type in the header, **but the payload is malformed: no boundary, no Content-Disposition**:

```
Jul 13, 2014 3:57:43 PM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor
INFORMATION: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Address: http://www.google.at/multipart
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Headers: {Content-Type=[multipart/form-data], Accept=[application/xml]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.outofrange.sscce</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrsclient</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
--------------------------------------
```

**If I fire my request against my real server (not only Google as a dummy address), I get a 400 - Bad Request response.**

Is Apache CXF able to automatically detect jersey-media-multipart and create a proxy?